# Minmax Scalar and Negative Values

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a numpy array `data` of shape - `[1000, 20, 20, 5, 10]` which has both postive and negative values. I am trying to scale the data using minmaxscalar but the values are different after inverse_transform.

code-

```
reshaped_data = data.reshape((1000, 20*20*5*10))
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
encodes = scaler.fit_transform(reshaped_data)
encodes = encodes.reshape((1000, 20, 20, 5, 10))

decodes = scaler.inverse_transform(encodes.reshape((1000, 20*20*5*10)))
decodes = decodes.reshape((1000, 20, 20, 5, 10))
np.array_equal(data, decodes) #False
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of numerical rounding in the any or all of `MinMaxScaler()`, `fit_transform()`, and `inverse_transform()` the values you will get back in `decodes` will not be precisely identical to arbitrary precision to the original data. The rounding, however takes place in a very high significant digit, so rather than comparing the exact numerical values, you can use the np.where() function to see if there is deviation to within your allowed tolerance.

For example, if you are ok with the decoded values agreeing to within `1e-5`, you can perform what you need as:

```
tolerance = 1.0e-5
len(np.where(np.abs(data - decodes) > tolerance)[0]) == 0
```

The above line will be false when any element of `data` disagrees with `decodes` to within `tolerance`. This should replace the line:

```
np.array_equal(data, decodes)
```

**EDIT**: for future reference, the best numpy-idiomatic way of achieving this is to use the `np.allclose` [function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html#numpy.allclose), like this:

```py
rel_tolerance = 1.0e-5
np.allclose(data, decodes, rtol=rel_tolerance)
```

which evaluates to true if every element in `data` and `decodes` agrees to within the relative tolerance.